# form not rendering in HAML

Tags: html, forms, haml

It is difficult to explain my issue, so I will post the relevant code and hopefully that will make more sense.

I have a form, which includes a second form.

_form.html.haml:

```
= form_for @question, :html => { :class => "form-horizontal" } do |f|
  ...
  %h3 Parts

  %ul
    = f.fields_for :question_parts, @question.question_parts do |builder|
      = render 'question_part_fields', f: builder
      = link_to_add_fields 'Add Part', f, :question_parts

  .form-group
    .col-sm-offset-2.col-sm-10
      = f.submit :class => 'btn btn-primary'
```

_question_part_fields.html.haml:

```
%li.question_parts
.......
    = f.fields_for :correct_answer do |builder|
      = render 'correct_answer_fields', f: builder

    .form-group
      .col-sm-offset-2.col-sm-10
        = f.hidden_field :_destroy
        = link_to 'Remove Part', '#', class: 'remove_fields'
    %hr
```

_correct_answer_fields.html.haml:

```
.form-group
  = f.label :correct_answer, :class => 'col-sm-2 control-label'
  .col-sm-10
    %h5 Raw (text, ASCIImath)
    = f.text_area :content, :class => 'form-control'
    %h5 Preview
    #answer_preview
```

The problem is that when I load the form, all the different parts load properly, but when I click "Add Part", it renders the _questions_part_fields, but not the _correct_answer_fields.

Any ideas why this is and how I could fix it?

Thanks

Comment: I've never used haml, but reading this, I have one question: are you sure that `@question.question_parts` has exactly what you expect? Excuse me if I'm asking a stupid question.

Comment: Hi, yes, @questions can have different parts, i.e. .question_parts

Comment: But are you sure that `@question.question_parts` isn't empty or something?

Comment: Yes I'm pretty sure...and the _question_parts form renders perfectly fine, it's the _correct_answer_fields that doesn't render...

Comment: I'm sorry then. It seems to me that the syntax is different. On `_form`, you have `f.fields_for :question_parts, @question.question_parts do |builder|` while on `_question_part_fields` you have `f.fields_for :correct_answer do |builder|` (notice the missing `@question.question_parts`). Or am I saying something wrong?